# how to remove this error TypeError: a.area is not a function at eval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

http://www.es6fiddle.net/iearlj80/

hello 
I am trying to learn ES6 .But I am getting error this **TypeError: a.area is not a function at eval** why ? Actually I am calling function function like this

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea()
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

var a =new Polygon(10,20)
alert(a.area())
```

when I used like this **a.calcArea()** it works but when i used like this **a.area()** it gives error ? why ?

Comment: Why do you use `get` in one definition but not the other? Maybe that's *why* there is a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are defining your function as `get area(){}` which is actually way to define getters on objects.

So you don't need to call it

say this

```
alert(a.area)
```

instead of

```
alert(a.area())
```

[*updated demo*](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iearwq1f/)

References(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: why area is function ? it is not property ?

Comment: @user944513: Functions can be properties as well. A property is simply an "entry" of an object. The *value* of a property can be arbitrary. It can be a number, string, object or even function. However `get` creates a special kind of property, an "accessor property" whose value is computed by the function you provide. Learn more about `get` before you use it (see MDN).

Answer (score 1):

`a.area()` would work if you had

```
area() {
```

but if you have

```
get area() {
```

you have declared a property getter, which means you would get the area by reading `.area` directly.

The first declares a class prototype property which has the value of a function.
The second declares a class prototype property which has an accessor 'getter' function. Attempting to access `.area` will call your `area` function and the result will be the returned value.

For example, for `.area()` to work with your syntax, it would be like:

```
get area(){
    return function(){
        return 4;
    };
}
```

Then you could do `a.area() === 4`, but then you might as well do

```
area(){
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: is get area() is property ? or function ?

Comment: @user944513 Everything is a property, its just that properties can either store values, or functions that are automatically called to get the value (which is what you are trying to use).